# What happens if my flight is delayed and I overstay my B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, lax

I have a B2 visa, and the admission stamp says I must leave by October 8th, so I booked my flight home for October 7th at 9PM.

Just in case something happens and my flight is delayed, does anyone know if it's possible to just book a random flight at LAX out of the country, or even a bus out of the country? I'm thinking, if I overstay my visa I'm obviously in a lot of trouble, so I would want to have a backup plan to get out of the country as soon as possible if my flight was delayed. Has anyone heard of, or experienced, anything like this?

Comment: Your visa expires? Or your I-94 expires? US visas are only for entry and when the visa expires is irrelevant to how long you can stay or when you can leave.

Comment: If your I-94 expires on October 8, that means you can leave on October 8, and not be overstaying. So if your flight is delayed for less than a day, you should be fine.

Comment: `spontaneous flight at LAX out of the country, or even a bus out of the country` You must have a lot of ca$h to spare for last minute international flights, unless you already have visas ready to be able to catch a cheap bus/flight to neighboring countries. If you are so paranoid about overstaying, don't be booking last minute flights.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. **USA visas do not say you must leave on any particular date.** Why did you make this edit?

Comment: Your other question says you already left the US after getting this stamp. So please take a moment and actually _read_ and try to understand the answer you have been given.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens if your USA visa expires while you are still in the country.

Unlike most countries, the USA visa expiration is not related to how long you can stay in the country.

Instead, the visa expiration indicates [the last day you can *enter* the USA](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html). Even if you had entered on the visa expiration day, you could receive a normal six months admission.

The date you must depart the USA is the date stamped into your passport when you entered the USA. If you cannot find the stamp or want to confirm the date, you can look at your [online I-94 record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/), which should also show the date you must depart.

---

I got suspicious and went to read your previous questions. They revealed that you have entered the US once before and were admitted until October 8, 2018, and that you got an admission stamp which was stamped partly across your visa. This is just a regular admission stamp for your visit. On your first visit using a visa, CBP will place the admission stamp so that it is partly on the visa. This does not cause the *visa* to expire. The visa expiration date remains as it was originally printed. It simply means your initial trip to the USA must end by October 8. But you already left the USA, so it is no longer relevant.

For example:

[image: US arrival stamp]

Here we see that this visitor's first visit to the US using this visa was in January 26, 2013, and she was admitted unitl July 25, 2013. But the visa remains valid for multiple entries and several more years.

Admission stamps you get for future visits will be placed elsewhere in your passport.